# Running massive calculation

Tags: algorithm, performance, parallel.foreach, operation, flops

I have a c# code like this

```
 Parallel.For(0, 10000, i =>
 {
   function getThePassphase(int length){
   }
 });
```

Use parallel method, it's capable of running my function "getThePassphase()" 10000 times per second on my i7 processor. Assume i want to run the calculation 1 quintillion times (10^18). May i ask if is there any hpc service or computer labs capable of complete such a task in a day? If most of the service use Linux & can't run c# properly, i can manage to convert it into c++

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, because it is not about programming. You are asking us to recommend an off-site resource.

Comment: @RossPresser sr, where can i post this question on stackchange? This site has lots of branchs & i don't know where to ask the question

Comment: To the first order approximation this is a simple math problem. The world's fastest computer does 143.5 petaflops, your i7 does how many? So now you can figure out, ballpark, if it's possible or not.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Stack Exchange site for a question like this, because these types of questions aren't what SE is built for.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). FYI, the world's fastest supercomputer can do 143.5 petaFLOPS, which is 1.435*10^17 floating point operations per second. So it could do what you want in a day if the operation that you're running requires around 12398.4 floating point operations.

Comment: You might want to consider posting a separate question regarding optimizing your `getThePassphrase()` function for performance.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131029-00/?p=2803) old problem.

Comment: @RossPresser Do you know any basic solution for this, in hardware or software? technically, this work like hashcat, the word generator was ok, can make 10000000 possible combinations but combine with the hash function it reduce to 10000, that's what i'm stucking with, the code run on pure CPU power which make me seek stronger hardware for the task

Comment: No, I do not. I think that with the current state of the art, as soon as you find yourself asking any question about processing a quintillion things, you need to choose a different approach.

Comment: The fact that you're willing to pay money in order to rent supercomputers to crack a password makes me suspect that you're attempting to do something malicious. Whether that's actually the case, you should know that unethical hacking such as cracking passwords can get you in a whole bunch of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming world's fastest computer (143.5 petaflops) and a pretty fast i7 (1 teraflop)

```
 10^18 / 24 / 60 / 60 /143500 < 10000 ?
 80655568 < 10000 ?
 false
```

So, no, there is no such [single] computer today, the fastest is still ~8,000 times too slow.  And even if we assume your i7 is slower and you can make the algorithm faster you'd still be unlikely to gain an 8,000x improvement.

Can you afford the electric bill for a day of compute on such a computer?!?

Comment: no, which is why i'm looking for an service for rent if available. but thanks for your answer. I read that the price to rent titan supercomputer was 2000$/hour which can do 38,360,000,000,000,000 calculation per seconds(2013 estimate). I was expected some service can do this easily

Comment: @DanMinhToan Think about it. Why would someone rent you a supercomputer for a price that is lower than the cost of the electricity? Like I said before, whatever you're trying to do, renting a supercomputer to compute some operation 1 quintillion times probably isn't the solution. So tell us what your real problem is so that we can suggest other solutions.

Comment: @FeiXiang i read that these supercomputer can do trillions of calculation per seconds which make me beleive it can complete my task easily. i don't have much experience in calculate performance though. It's just a simple brute force password function & i want to run it as much in the shortest time as possible